# Print the last IP found before each line containing a specific word?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would like to extract all the last IPs before matching a line with the word "abc".

My file :

```
IP address: 10.1.1.1
IP address: 192.168.1.1        
some text
some text abc
more lines of text
IP address: 10.1.1.1
some text
IP address: 127.0.0.1
some text abc
```

Result expected:

```
192.168.1.1
127.0.0.1
```

What I tried:

I searched the lines containing `abc` in specific files and displayed the 50 lines before that, then I looked for the lines with IP address and finally extract the IP numbers of the result.

```
grep -Ri "*file*.txt" "abc" . -B 50 | grep "IP address: " | cut -d " " -f 3 > IP_list.txt
```

However, the size of the text can change between files and sometimes one file can contain many lines with `abc` So the results are not reliable.

I would like a more "clean" approach. Thanks !

Comment: What does this mean?  There are 3 lines that contain an ip address and match the string `abc`.  Why is 10.1.1.1 omitted from the result?  Neither of the lines that contain the strings in the desired output match the string `word`; why are they in the output?

Comment: In that case, if the naive match is adequate: `perl -nE 'if( /(\d*\.\d*\.\d*\.\d*)/ ) { $ip =$1 } say $ip if(/word/)' input`

Comment: Exactly @Sundeep. In fact there is some text between each IP and the line containing `word` , it is not the previous line.

Comment: Either way, you are expected to exhibit some effort - if nothing else, what did you search for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?  This should be quite trivial in Awk.

Comment: @Sundeep I grep the word and printed the 50 lines before. Then I looked for the first IP that I met. But taking the 50 lines can display other IPs or no IP as it depends of the size of the text. I have no knowledge about the regex or sed command but I knew we can do it ^^. Finally, your perl command has done the job ! Can you briefly explain it ? thank you !

Comment: @Sundeep, maybe I spoke too soon. The command did not find the IP.  :/

Comment: how about `awk '/abc/{print ip} /IP address:/{ip=$3}'`

Comment: @Sundeep, Nice one. since OP added efforts in his post, I have voted to reopen it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers.

Finally I simple solved my problem by using an "OR" in my grep command that list all IP and abc words from the top to the bottom. Then I pass the result to an other grep to display the first IP above the abc words. Finally I just output the rest of the IP address.

```
grep 'IP address:\|abc' myfile | grep abc -B1 | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" > all_ip_linked_to_abc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/^IP/{ip=$NF} /abc/{print ip}' file
192.168.1.1
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: yeah, i thought about making it more robust in case there's other input than the OP showed in the question but figured I'd see if the OP had a problem and if so then I'd push back for a more representative example in the question and THEN beef it up appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative `gnu awk` that uses `abc` as record separator:

```
awk -v RS='abc' '/IP address:/ {
print gensub(/.* (([0-9]+\.){3}[0-9]+).*/, "\\1", 1)}' file
```

```
192.168.1.1
127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^IP/h;/abc/{g;s/.*: //p}' file
```

If a line begins `IP` store it in the hold space.

If a line contains `abc`, replace it by the stored IP and print it.